# What's the underscore.js equivalent to LINQ's SelectMany operator?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, linq

Imagine I have a nested array structure.

```
var nested = [ [1], [2], [3] ];
```

Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), how would I produce a flattened array?

In C# you would use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) like this:

```
var flattened = nested.SelectMany(item => item);
```

Note that the lambda in this case selects the nested item directly, but it could have been any arbitrary expression.

In jQuery, it's possible to just use:

```
var flattened = $.map(nested, function(item) { return item; });
```

However this approach doesn't work with underscore's [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) function.

So how would I get the flattened array `[1, 2, 3]` using underscore.js?

Comment: you could also write: _.map(nested, function(item) {return item[0];})

Comment: @Darragh, that would work for my specific example, but not when the child arrays contain multiple elements.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
var nested = [ [1], [2], [3] ];
var flattened = _.flatten(nested);
```

Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yE9d/)

Comment: Nice and easy! Why didn't I see that in their documentation? :)

Comment: Notice: pass shallow=true, if you only want one level of flattening (like SelectMany does): `_.flatten(nested, true)`

Comment: [`flatten`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) appears to only do one level by default now; they've added `flattenDeep` and `flattenDepth`.

Comment: If anyone interested in more comparisons between LINQ and underscore.js I wrote article: https://www.vladopandzic.com/javascript/comparing-underscore-js-with-linq/

Answer (score 45):

If you have a slightly more complicated array, say one coming from JSON, you can take advantage of the [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method as well, extracting the specific property you are interested in, similar to `parents.SelectMany(parent => parent.Items);`

```
// underscore version
var allitems = _.flatten(_.pluck(parents, 'items'));
```

`allitems` is now the array of all subitems from the parents, `[a,b,c,d]`.

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48wZV/) showing the same thing.

---

Or, if you are using lodash you can do the same thing by using the [_.flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs#flatMap) function which is available since version 4. Cred to Noel for pointing it out in the comments.

```js
var parents = [
  { name: 'hello', items: ['a', 'b'] },
  { name: 'world', items: ['c', 'd'] }
];


// version 1 of lodash, straight up
var allitems = _.flatMap(parents, 'items');
logIt('straight', allitems);

// or by wrapping the collection first
var allitems = _(parents)
  .flatMap('items')
  .value();
logIt('wrapped', allitems);

// this basically does _(parents).map('items').flatten().value();

function logIt(wat, value) {
  console.log(wat, value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

---

In case you want to do more stuff and don't want to chain operators, you can use the [`flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flow) function to get the same effect. This is useful if you are using TypeScript and importing each operator individually, since you can then optimize your final payload.

```js
const parents = [
  { name: 'hello', items: ['a', 'b'] },
  { name: 'world', items: ['c', 'd'] }
];
logIt('original', parents);

const result = _.flow(
  (collection) => _.flatMap(collection, (item) => item.items),
  (flattened) => flattened.filter((item) => item !== 'd')
)(parents);
logIt('result without "d"', result);

function logIt(wat, value) {
  console.log(wat, value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Though not available in underscore, with lodash, you could simplify from using `map` and `flatten` to only using `flatMap`, like this: `_.flatMap(parents, "items")`).

Comment: Thanks @Noel, I'll add it to my answer. Didn't know about that one when I wrote my answer

Answer (score 3):

We can also make [Patrick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25126109/65387) into a mixin so that it becomes chainable:

```
_.mixin({
    selectMany: function(collection, iteratee=_.identity) {
        return _.flatten(_.map(collection, iteratee));
    }
});
```

Examples:

```
let sample = [{a:[1,2],b:'x'},{a:[3,4],b:'y'}];

console.log(_.selectMany(sample, 'a')); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
console.log(_.chain(sample).selectMany(o => o.a).filter(a => a % 2 === 0).map(a => a * 3).value()); // [ 6, 12 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any methods in lodash that work quite like `SelectMany`, so I created one using pure JS:

```
Array.prototype.selectMany = function(fn) {
    return Array.prototype.concat(...this.map(fn));
};
```

Boom.

```
> console.log([{a:[1,2],b:'x'},{a:[3,4],b:'y'}].selectMany(o => o.a));
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: Really? I have included a working sample in my answer.. What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: @Patrick The order of operations. It gets confusing when there's nesting: `a.selectMany(b => b.c.selectMany(d => d.e))`. Try re-writing that using your solution.